# Why Can't I Edit This Question?

Tags: support, editing

[This question has some serious formatting issues](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/823/how-to-write-test-class-for-this-trigger), yet the Edit link is disabled for me—anybody know why? I've never seen that before!

Comment: which question?

Comment: It could be that it's already edited, and until reviewed and accepted I think it's locked.

Comment: Whoops - school boy error! Link added!

Comment: I figured it will be that one. I edited it today already. I assume after approval, it will open for more edits :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct. If there pending edits (submitted but not yet approved), the edit link will be unclickable for other users.

Comment: ANSWERJACKING !  :-)

Comment: @Saariko A little. If your answer was an answer rather than a comment, I would've upvoted (and commented to confirm that you are correct). Don't worry, I don't get rep for that here. ;)